# Renaming files in the folder sequentially

Tags: matlab, recursion, logic, rename

I have a bunch of files with random names in a folder, and I am trying to rename them sequentially as Sample1_1, Sample1_2, Sample2_1, Sample2_2,Sample3_1, Sample3_2 and so on...

My code so far:

```
%%reading files in the directory and renaming it

files = dir('*.NEF');

for i = 1:name1(files)
    for j = 1:2
        filename = files(i).name;
        I = imread(filename);
        imwrite(I,sprintf('Sample%d_%d.NEF',i,j));
        delete(filename);
    end
end
```

Comment: what does not work? What kind of output do you get?

Comment: code stop after renaming one sample

Comment: ok. And out of curiosity what is name1(files)?

Comment: @Heyyyy, I think your code is ok only if you write "length" instead of "name1".

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a simple code which produces the names you want. To simplify things, I create 2 arrays, each containing the numbers we want to place into the file names. Then it's easy to loop through the arrays and get the correct numbers. It's quite easy to implement for your application:

```
clear
clc

%// In my example I generate only 8 names
NumSamples = 4;

CheckSample = kron(1:NumSamples,ones(1,2));
OneOrTwo = repmat([1 2],1,NumSamples);
```

CheckSample and OneOrTwo are the 2 arrays I was referring to. You can see the correspondence to create the file names with appropriate numbers.

```
CheckSample =

     1     1     2     2     3     3     4     4


OneOrTwo =

     1     2     1     2     1     2     1     2

%// For demonstration purposes, create a cell array containing the filenames.
NameCell = cell(1,NumSamples*2);

%/ Now loop through each image (in your case) to generate the file name.

for k = 1:2*NumSamples

        NameCell{k} = sprintf('Sample%d_%d',CheckSample(k),OneOrTwo(k));

end

NameCell
```

NameCell looks like this:

```
NameCell = 

  Columns 1 through 4

    'Sample1_1'    'Sample1_2'    'Sample2_1'    'Sample2_2'

  Columns 5 through 8

    'Sample3_1'    'Sample3_2'    'Sample4_1'    'Sample4_2'
```

From your code above you could do something like this:

```
    files = dir('*.NEF');
    NumSamples = length(files)/2;

    CheckSample = kron(1:NumSamples,ones(1,2));
    OneOrTwo = repmat([1 2],1,NumSamples);

for k = 1:2*NumSamples

    filename = files(k).name;
    I = imread(filename);

    CurrentName = sprintf('Sample%d_%d',CheckSample(k),OneOrTwo(k));
    CurrentName = strcat(CurrentName,'.NEF'); %// Keep right file extension.

    imwrite(I,CurrentName);

end
```

Comment: @Heyyy so did you try my suggestion?